# OpenGL убрать смешивание, но оставить прозрачность

Tags: opengl

Каким образом можно отменить смешивание в зонах, обведенных голубым цветом? Чтобы то, что ближе к камере полностью перекрывало то, что от камеры дальше.
Отрисовка треугольниками и цвет rgba - 0, 1, 1, 0.5.
[image: OpenGL]

Comment: Например, рисовать спереди-назад. В таком режиме, дальняя геометрия не будет проходить тест глубины и не будет рисоваться там, где уже что-то есть ближе.

Comment: А разве тест глубины учитывает полупрозрачные объекты?

Comment: Тест глубины учитывает любые объекты. Иногда, как хак, можно даже полностью невидимыми рисовать ) Еще вариант, через стенсил - нарисовать объект в "маску" (stencil), потом нарисовать заливку цветом (она будет по маске), потом выключить маску.